# How to deploy a whole notebook on wolfram cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, deployment, cloud-deploy

In the doc section `howto/DeployInteractiveContentInTheWolframCloud`

It is mentioned

> You can deploy the entire notebook to the cloud using CloudExport:

using

```
CloudExport[nbexpr, "NB"]
```

what is `nbexpr`?

I have a notebook which contains several interactive manipulate and I want to push it to cloud for other people to view. How to do it?

Comment: One way: File -> Save to Wolfram Cloud, then go to the Wolfram Cloud and deploy it with the GUI as a "Cloud CDF".

Comment: @C.E. Hi, C.E.  I don't know what is wrong, it always warns me "not connected to wolfram cloud" when " save to Wolfram Cloud". http://pasteboard.co/aInXmKuvR.png   Though I can use `CloudDeploy` without problem

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple things you can do here. The simplest is generally to use [`CloudDeploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDeploy.html) on the [`NotebookObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookObject.html). E.g.:

```
CloudDeploy[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Alternatively you can deploy the expression:

```
CloudDeploy[NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

If you want to deploy it in downloadable form use `"Package"` and [`CloudExport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudExport.html):

```
CloudExport[NotebookGet[], "Package"]
```

And if you want it to automatically download as a .nb:

```
CloudExport[NotebookGet[], "Package",
 FileNameTake@NotebookFileName[]]
```

Surely you've found your answer by now, but I thought this was worth putting out there for others.

Comment: I have a demonstration with `Manipulate` and like to upload it to Cloud for others to run without seeing the actual `Code` behind the calculations. How can I do it? I tried manythings but could not find a solution.